# Dynamic url shortening script for text input

Tags: url-shortener

We are looking for script, which automatically detects url, as you type and shorten it, in text input window, before press "submit". The shortening service used is http://yourls.org/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried implementing one yourself? Deploy the shortener to your own web site (it's written in PHP, as far as I can see from a cursory glance at the web site) and provide a simple Ajax endpoint which will dynamically perform a shortening conversion, then implement calls to that from the main page using JavaScript.

You might want to impose a reasonable delay to allow the user to finish typing, to avoid performing lots of unnecessary conversions of bogus URLs (which may require, e.g. writes to a file or database - I haven't looked at how the library referenced does things).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve; if you create new shortened URLs for each substring before the user has finished typing the full URL, you will just proliferate your database.
I don't see how shortening a URL before it's finished makes sense.

If you want to relieve the user from the arduous task of clicking the submit button, then initiate the submit using javascript (jQuery, or something). I'm not sure if that's what you want to do.

Comment: We are looking for similar feature, like in TweetDeck. If you started to write tweet and insert some link - you should now when you are reaching 140 characters limit. SO the best implementation is "as you tape" or paste link and press space - link is automatically shortened and you could see actuall characters left.

Answer (score 0):

http://monkeytooth.net/2010/12/htaccess-php-how-to-wordpress-slugs/
simple means of implementing the concept its a lot more easier than one would think. Querying a DB or some other means of matching the slug/id with the that of which is found in the URL wouldn't be all to hard either. The linked article doesn't really go in depth as what to do next but catching and breaking the URL apart is the essential process of making it work. I have person used the method myself on several sites and it works like a charm for me and the sites it was used on.